# change background color of parent div if radio button is checked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to change the background color of a div containing a radio button when the button is checked.

This is the html

```
  <div class="testing-container">
            <input id=“test” type="radio" name="option-{{ option_index }}" value=“test”/>
          <label for="swatch">
         Test
        </label>
      </div>
```

I've tried it using jquery like this

```
  $(".testing-container input").change(function() { 
    if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
        $(this).parent().css("background", "black");
    }
});
```

Comment: well for me you code works what browser are you having this issue as the divs color changes as soon as i select the radio button

Answer (score 1):

Putting my solution here, just in case someone run across the same issue I was having.

Trying to set the background color of the parent li tag of the selected radio button. I came up with the following JQuery solution.

My HTML looks like this:

```
<li class="zb-list-group-item pl-3">
      <div class="custom-control custom-radio">
         <input type="radio" id="shippingMethod_2_2_1_1" name="shippingMethod_2_2_1" class="custom-control-input submit-radio" value="4|1 day shipping|Priority Mail Express|0|0|0.0000">
         <label class="custom-control-label" for="shippingMethod_2_2_1_1">
         <span class="d-block text-success font-weight-bold">Tuesday Jan 08, 2019</span>
         <span class="d-block">$0.00 - 3-5 day shipping</span>
         </label>
      </div>
   </li>
```

Not only did I need the radio button change event to fire, but I also needed the background color to set on page load.

JQuery looks like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  // Find and select background color of selected shipping option parent li
    $(".custom-control-input:checked").each(function () {
    $('.zb-list-group-item.highlight').removeClass('highlight');
    $(this).closest('.zb-list-group-item').addClass('highlight');
  });

  // On change of shipping options change background color of parent li
  $('.custom-control-input').on("change", function () {
    // Only remove the class in the specific `box` that contains the radio
    $('.zb-list-group-item.highlight').removeClass('highlight');
    $(this).closest('.zb-list-group-item').addClass('highlight');
  });

});
```

Working JSFiddle can be found here:
https://jsfiddle.net/kbLxwdr2/1/

Hopefully this helps someone out :)

Answer (score -1):

You are targeting the wrong element.  Your html class is `testing-container` while in your jQuery, you are targeting `test-container input`.  `test-container` vs `testing-container`

## edit 2

Also your quotes in your html are not actually quotes.  They are other characters that looks like quotes.

## edit 3

Since you have fixed these things, your issues should be resolved.  Here is a snippet with your exact code.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".testing-container input").change(function() {
    if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
      $(this).parent().css("background", "black");
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="testing-container">
 <input id=“test” type="radio" name="option-{{ option_index }}" value=“test”/>
 <label for="swatch">
  Test
 </label>
</div>
```

Comment: sry, that was just a typo

Comment: Did those suggestions fix your issues?

Comment: With multiple radio buttons, this code leaves them black when another radio button is selected.

Comment: The original question does not ask for a toggle feature.